# Selenium - PhantomJS - Findelements in DOM traversal is slow

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

For, reasons, I'm trying to recurse through the DOM using Selenium/PhantomJS. 
It works but its slow and I dont know why. 
Findelements seems to take about 250ms every time.

I've tried zeroing the implicit wait with not much success. I've also tried using the Xpath with no real change.

Here's the code, any suggestions ?

```
    public static void RecurseDomFromTop()
    {
        DomRecursor( pjsDriver.FindElement( By.TagName( "*" ) ) );
    }

    public static void DomRecursor( IWebElement node )
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> iwes = node.FindElements( By.TagName( "*" ) );

        foreach (IWebElement iwe in iwes)
        {
           DomRecursor( iwe );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why in the world you want to query each tag?

Comment: I want to accurately compare two doms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are taking to compare two doms this way is wrong. Every time you make Selenium request there is a HTTP request created that is sent to the driver, which send it to the browser, which then sends it back to driver and driver back to you language binding. There is a lot of overhead involved in this.

Instead what you should do is use `driver.PageSource` and get the whole HTML response in a single call. Then later you can use HTML parsing libraries which are at least 10x faster than the approach you are taking now.

Look at below article which uses HtmlAgilityPack for getting DOM data

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H